# jacoco: Set coverage metric

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have the following result

[image]

Of the coverage totals that appear in the image (20% and 2%) I want to establish a minimum
I have been trying the following code but without the expected results

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.7</version> <!-- Usa la versión más reciente -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>PACKAGE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.8</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```